# Choose interpreter TCL C API

Tags: c, tcl

I have a couple tcl interpreters on my system and i'd like to pick which one the C API for tcl uses. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit lost. What are you asking? Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: are you just asking for 'which tclsh' perhaps?

Comment: @jk: yes, I want to be able to point it at a particular tclsh

Answer (score 2):

The C api doesn't pick the interpreter, you pick the C api corresponding to the interpreter you wish to use, by changing the include and link paths.

Answer (score 1):

You pass the interpreter *to* the [C API](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/contents.htm), having first created it with [`Tcl_CreateInterp`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/Interp.htm). For example [`Tcl_Eval`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclLib/Eval.htm)'s interface is:

```
int Tcl_Eval(Tcl_Interp *interp, const char *script)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, when running a Tcl program you pick the API by selecting the interpreter. You can do this explicitly by naming the interpreter program as exactly as you choose:

```
bash$  /my/special/place/bin/tclsh8.6 thescript.tcl ...
```

Or you can put this trick with the standard `env` program at the start your executable Tcl script and rely on the OS to process your PATH environment to select a suitable one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env tclsh8.6
```

It's standard to install Tcl interpreters with the version in their names so that you can easily have different versions on the system.

---

When creating a C program that uses the Tcl library, you select the headers and libraries (which are usually best regarded as a matched set) by setting your include and library path. Unix compilers usually use `-I` and `-L` options to do that respectively; a script (`tclConfig.sh`) is typically also installed to make getting those options right easier. Note that while Tcl's libraries are usually versioned in their names, Tcl's header files are not; if you install multiple versions of the headers into the same place, only the most recent version will be usable.

It's possible to use standard options to `configure` when building Tcl to make everything split up better.